# How to compile with a specified target using Makefile in Java?

Tags: java, makefile, compilation

I am trying to write a Makefile for my java project. My aim is to:

**1.** Compile with the target make-java

**2.** Run with the target run-java

I have seen on the Internet this example of the Makefile:

```
  JFLAGS = -g
    JC = javac
    
    .SUFFIXES: .java .class
    
    .java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
    
    
    CLASSES = \
              Main.java \
              Book.java \
              Library.java 
    
    default: classes
    
    classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
    
    clean:
        $(RM) *.class
        
    run-java:
        java Main
```

My problem is the make-java target (1st option), when I try to change the:

```
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

to

```
make-java:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

It doesn't work. Can you give me a solution on how to change it in order to compile with the following command: make make-java

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change that rule.  That is a [suffix rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html); it's basically a template that says "here's how to build a .class file from a .java file".  The combination of the `.SUFFIXES` setting of `.java .class` and a rule with the special form `.java.class` has this effect.

If you change it, you remove make's understanding of how to build .class files.

You want to leave that alone and add this instead:

```
make-java: classes
```

to tell make that it should build all the `.class` files when `make make-java` is invoked.